# How to know 3g DNS setting on Android?

Tags: 3g, dns

I want to know what is the DNS configuration of the 3G connection of my Android. Only to know, not to change (yet).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot) on my device.

I can get DNS information by using `getprop | grep dns`

[image: ConnectBot capture]